# Switching between log4j configs

Tags: java, spring, maven, logging

I've just implemented Spring profiles, in my `web.xml` I added a default profile:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
    <param-value>prod</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and in my `applicationContext.xml` I can now easily switch between which config file to use:

```
 <beans profile="dev">
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/dev.properties"/>
    </beans>
    <beans profile="prod">
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/prod.properties"/>
    </beans>
```

and I've made `mvn jetty:run` always use the dev profile:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
    <configuration>
        <webAppConfig>
            <contextPath>/${project.artifactId}</contextPath>
            <sessionHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler">
            <sessionManager implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager">
            <!-- Disable url sessions using JSessionID -->                                              
            <sessionIdPathParameterName>none</sessionIdPathParameterName>
            </sessionManager>
            </sessionHandler>
        </webAppConfig>
        <httpConnector>
            <port>9091</port>
        </httpConnector>
            <systemProperties>
                <systemProperty>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </systemProperty>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

How would I switch between different log4j configurations?

I'm using sl4j with log4j:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

In dev I log to `stdout` and in production I log to both `stdout` and `queue` (queue being rabbitMQ)?

Obviously Spring is not yet loaded when log4j starts up (no pun intended), so it seems Spring profiles are out.

How can I easily switch between different log4j configurations - `log4j-dev.properties` and `log4j-prod.properties`

Comment: You need to use system property. Please refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544718/spring-mvc-loading-different-log4j-file-per-build-environment.